# Como colocar os ícones do *Bootstrap* (`glyphicon-bootstrap`) no menu do Yii framework

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, bootstrap-glyphicons

Estou começando um projeto na empresa onde desenvolvo, e estamos sendo **obrigado** a usar o *Yii Framework* junto com o *Bootstrap*, mas não estou conseguindo colocar os ícones do *Bootstrap* (`glyphicon-bootstrap`) no menu, segue exemplo do código:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',
   array('htmlOptions'=>array("class"=>"nav", "id"=>"side-menu"), 'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
        array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
        array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact'), 'className '=>'tafaera'),
        array('label'=>'Charts', 'url'=>array('/submenu/sub0'),
            'submenuOptions'=>array('class'=>'nav nav-second-level'),
            'items'=>array(
                    array('label'=>'Sub 1.1','tag'=>'tafarel' ,'url'=>array('/submenu/sub1')),
                    array('label'=>'Sub 1.2', 'url'=>array('/submenu/sub2')),
                    array('label'=>'Sub 1.3','url'=>array('/submenu/sub3')
                )
            )
        ),
        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        array('label'=>'Hola', 'url'=>array('/hola/index')),
        array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    ),
));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque essa opção `'encodeLabel'=>false`, igual exemplo abaixo.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', 
     array('encodeLabel'=>false, ....
```

No seu código:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',
   array("encodeLabel"=>false, 'htmlOptions'=>array("class"=>"nav", "id"=>"side-menu"), 'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact'), 'className '=>'tafaera'),
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> Charts', 'url'=>array('/submenu/sub0'),
            'submenuOptions'=>array('class'=>'nav nav-second-level'),
            'items'=>array(
                    array('label'=>'Sub 1.1','tag'=>'tafarel' ,'url'=>array('/submenu/sub1')),
                    array('label'=>'Sub 1.2', 'url'=>array('/submenu/sub2')),
                    array('label'=>'Sub 1.3','url'=>array('/submenu/sub3')
                )
            )
        ),
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> Hola', 'url'=>array('/hola/index')),
        array('label'=>'<i class=""></i> Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    ),
));
```

Nesse [**Link - How do I add image into CMenu**](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9785-how-do-i-add-image-into-cmenu/), tem a explicação de alguns usuários

Comment: Não deu certo... o Yii ainda não está reconhecendo a tag <i class=""> do bootstrap, ele coloca o texto ao invés de aparecer o ícone

Comment: Eu to achando que é o local que ta errado, alterei o local dá uma olhada! ve se funciona @Tafarel_Brayan

Comment: Agora sim, deu certo.... eu tbm fiz um teste indo em: framework>zii>widgets>Cmenu.php
Lá tem uma opção de public $encodeLabel=true; e coloquei com ofalse e tbm deu certo !

Comment: @Tafarel_Brayan era realmente o local é que é tanto array que fiquei perdido kkkkkkk mas, que bom deu certo resolve a questão ....

Comment: Sou iniciante...como coloco que foi resolvido ?